# SabreDAV - Why are calendar events stored as BLOB in the PDO backend?

Tags: php, sabredav

I'm currently experimenting with SabreDAV, a WebDAV/CalDAV/CardDAV server for PHP.

As part of the download, there is a PDO backend that stores calendar events in a database like MySQL.

I noticed that SabreDAV uses a BLOB field to store the iCal data for the event in 1 field, and not in properly normalised fields in the row.

```
mysql> select * from calendarobjects \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        id: 2
  calendardata: BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//Mac OS X 10.10.5//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Brussels
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=-1SU
DTSTART:19810329T020000
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=10;BYDAY=-1SU
DTSTART:19961027T030000
TZNAME:CET
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
CREATED:20150825T141801Z
UID:B26931A6-6F8A-4CB6-95F2-C5567B7D64BA
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20150826T151500
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SUMMARY:My meeting
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20150826T143000
DTSTAMP:20150825T141801Z
SEQUENCE:0
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR

           uri: B26931A6-6F8A-4CB6-95F2-C5567B7D64BA.ics
    calendarid: 1
  lastmodified: 1440512292
          etag: 969a888bab9c906f0d7f10c23a856341
          size: 712
 componenttype: VEVENT
firstoccurence: 1440592200
 lastoccurence: 1440594900
           uid: B26931A6-6F8A-4CB6-95F2-C5567B7D64BA
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see there is 1 big field "calendar data" that contains everything in iCal format.

From my brief exploration of Milton (the Java counterpart of SabreDAV) it looked like this was also the case there, so it's not only in SabreDAV. But, I may be mistaken.

Is there a particular architectural reason why one would store the iCal data in a BLOB instead of storing the parsed data? I iCal data potentially so complex it cannot fit in a fully normalised way? Or, do you think the developer chose this to save time?

I was hoping to store the data in columns and rows, so I could easily generate a table on a website with calendar events...but now I'd need to parse out all the data and I cannot use SQL... or I'd need to use a full CalDAV client...but that's a overkill.

One particular problem I have already discovered is that a repeating event is 1 record in the DB and not multiple records. Determining the individual events will be very difficult now.

Comment: Take a look at the 148 page RFC (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) for iCal and see if you can can come up with a simple database schema for handle it all. I can see an advantage in picking out some bits of data (organiser and dates perhaps?) to store in normalised fields to assist in searching, but beyond that what is to gain?

Comment: That was my idea as well, but before getting started I wanted to make sure there is no "big reason" why it can't work. I'm not familiar enough with the format and know there are many special cases, like repeating events for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really hard to fully normalize the format into a RDMS. Many properties can appear multiple times, custom properties must be supported, as well as custom parameters.

The gain, as Eborbob also mentions would be in making some of this data easily searchable/indexable, and this is actually also happening for a few fields, including the `UID`.